# Cannot set privacy while creating a Facebook Album

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I cannot set the privacy while creating a new Album in fb using facebook-c#-sdk 5.0.25

```
var albumDetails = new Dictionary<string, object>();
albumDetails.Add("name", "test name");
albumDetails.Add("description", "test description");
albumDetails.Add("privacy", "ALL_FRIENDS"); // I get an error here, 
//Invalid Privacy value
var fbResult = fb.Post("me/albums", albumDetails);
```

I tried setting to other values like "EVERYONE" but without success. Please let me know what is the correct set of values.

Thanks,
Partha

Comment: According to [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.createAlbum/) page, it should be a json encoded value something like (i suppose): `[value: 'ALL_FRIENDS']` or `{value: 'ALL_FRIENDS'}`

Comment: I've added it as answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, but I still can't get it to work myself. Can you please post an example of the working solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.createAlbum/) page, it should be a json encoded value something like (i suppose): `[value: 'ALL_FRIENDS']` or `{value: 'ALL_FRIENDS'}`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :-

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.name = theName;
parameters.privacy = "{'value':'" + theValue + "'}";
```